# Display Japanese characters in my HTML

Tags: php, mysql, html, character-encoding

I've googled this but some of the questions seem a bit of of date. I'll ask a fresh one!

We would like to translate some of our webpages into Japanese. We want to have a MySQL table with 2 columns, English and Japanese.

I want to output the Japanese rows if a certain condition is met (such as a querystring value).

To test this quickly I have pasted some Japanese words into an HTML file and tried to preview in the browser but all I get is question marks.

町/市* - seems to be working on StackOverflow!

In my header is:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I was under the impression this was what I was meant to use for them to display correctly. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Change the encoding in your browser

Comment: Is your text-editor also using UTF-8 ? This is most probably the issue... Charset can be a pain in the ass, you really need to ensure the whole chain is using UTF-8. It will become even worse when moving content in the database...